# rails cucumber windows 7 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-7, cucumber

use ruby 1.9.2
rails 3.1.3
rake 0.8.7
and when rake cucumber start i have this message

[full console log](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40916179/ruby-windows.txt)

Google help me to find CUCUMBER_FORWARD_SLASH_PATHS=true, but the problem not solved

Comment: Why '...(cut some tests)...'?  I'd expect the relevant output to be in there...

Comment: can you execute `bundle exec cucumber --profile default` and provided that output? I don't see any particular error there that could provide more details.

Comment: attach link to full console log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you're receiving and the error triggered by Rake are correct.

cucumber is being executed and missing steps are required, so the exit code of the child process (invoked by rake) is non-zero.

Rake treats all the process that exit with non-zero as error and thus, generate the `rake aborted!` output.

You can avoid the double nesting and the error generated by rake by simply running the same command it is executing:

```
bundle exec cucumber
```

And use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like expected behaviour to me.  The Rake task is running cucumber with the `-S` flag ('strict', meaning it will fail if any steps are undefined), and you have a lot of undefined steps, so Cucumber is exiting with a failure code as expected.  Rake is simply picking up on this and reporting the error.

To fix this, I'd suggest following the advice given in the Cucumber output, and implement the missing step definitions.

EDIT: As Luis pointed out in the comments, the `-S` flag is on the `ruby` executable, not `cucumber`.  By a lucky coincidence, the OP's `default` cucumber profile also had the `--strict` flag on so the fix was the same!

Comment: thx, remove from config/cucumber.yml --strict parameter, and it`s work without any errors

Comment: glad my answer helped, but do be aware that if you have undefined steps, then your cucumber tests aren't actually 'passing' - you've just made Rake ignore the problem!

Comment: @Luis - the [source](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/blob/master/lib/cucumber/cli/options.rb#L250) says that it _is_ strict...

Comment: @JonM : the order of the options is important, note that is `ruby -S bundle exec cucumber` so -S option applies to Ruby executable, not cucumber.

Comment: @Luis - good call, I hadn't spotted that!  Quite lucky then that strict mode *did* turn out to be the problem...